# How to Load Dynatree via Ajax using MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynatree

Please someone help. 
I cannot work out how to load a Dynatree from the server. 
Instead of getting a tree I get "Load error! (error)"
I have read every single part of the documentaion and read hundreds of stackoverflow type answers and still do not understand, so I am hoping someone will just tell me what to do.

This is what I have:

**VIEW**

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>LoadAjax</title>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src='../../Scripts/jquery.cookie.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../../Content/skin/ui.dynatree.css' />
  <script src='../../Scripts/jquery.dynatree.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $("#tree").dynatree({
        initAjax: { url: "/LoadAjax/GetNodes" }
      });

    });    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  public ActionResult GetNodes()
    {
      var n1 = new DynaNode { title = "Node 1", key = "k1", isLazy = false };
      var n2 = new DynaNode { title = "Node 2", key = "k2", isLazy = false };
      var n3 = new DynaNode { title = "Node 3", key = "k3", isLazy = false };
      var nodeArray = new List<DynaNode> {n1, n2, n3};
      return Json(nodeArray);
    }
```

**CLASS**

```
  public class DynaNode
  {
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool isFolder { get; set; }
    public bool isLazy { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; } 
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I found the problem. I am embarrased to admit that it was a beginner's mistake.

**VIEW**

```
initAjax: {
  type: "POST", // This was needed
   url: "/DynaTree/GetNodes"
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost] // This was needed
public JsonResult GetNodes(string key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this solution, please:

```
return Json(nodeArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think your answer is correct, but you can make it even better if you explain why it is necessary to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` parameter