# Dynatree init from external data not working

Tags: treeview, web2py, dynatree

First time on Stack Overflow :-). I have been using the [Leo Outliner](http://webpages.charter.net/edreamleo/front.html) mainly to organize my task and writings and works pretty well to let me clarify my mind on complex subjects, but I cant not share my clarities easily with others because they don't use Leo. I have made a small exportation script from Leo to Dynatree just as a test and it works pretty well, so I thought that is was time create a web outliner, using web2py + dynatree. The problem is that dynatree works only for static data that is inside the script, but trying to use code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#tree").dynatree({
         // In real life we would call a URL on the server like this:
             //          initAjax: {
             //              url: "/getTopLevelNodesAsJson",
             //              data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
             //              },
        // .. but here we use a local file instead:
        initAjax: {
            url: "sample-data1.json"
            data: { mode: "all" }
            },
        onActivate: function(node) {
            $("#echoActive").text(node.data.title);
        },
        onDeactivate: function(node) {
            $("#echoActive").text("-");
        }
    });
});
```

The part that loads sample-data1.json is not working, no matter that the file exists and it has the proper permissions. I have searched here:

[How to Load Dynatree via Ajax using MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609605/how-to-load-dynatree-via-ajax-using-mvc)
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/dynatree/kZqIO1zCTSU/HYTFe9O2docJ

and others places on the web but I cant find how to enable this loading from external data. I have even thought in change my library for YUI or ExtJS. I now that there is a support for trees on web2py using [jstree](http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_jstree), but, in contrast with dynatree, YUI or ExtJS, JsTree documentation is not very newbie friendly.

Any pointer to a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the file located?

The best is to put the file under static folder

`web2py/applications/yourapp/static/sample-data1.json`

So you need to tell your Javascript to load this from static folder.

```
initAjax: {
    url: "yourapp/static/sample-data1.json",
    data: { mode: "all" }}
```

Or you can create the url dynamically

```
<script>

var url_to_sample_data = "{{=URL('static', 'sample-data1.json')}}";

.....

initAjax: {
            url: url_to_sample_data,
            data: { mode: "all" }
            }

.....

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, as always. All dynatree related files are in `/static/js/dynatree/` and I'm pretty sure that sample-data.json is located at the specified url and completely accessible from there. At [here](http://www.wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html) you can see "Instead of passing an array of data objects, we can pass a url in the initAjax option that will be used to contact an Ajax web service" I don't know which part is playing the role of an "Ajax web service", may be here lays the clue...